# "Where" to refer to a point in time

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, synonyms

I'm a non-native speaker, wondering whether the following construction is correct:

> It had been a bad day followed by an awful night **where** he found himself in the most inconvenient circumstances.

If not, would it be correct to use *when*, instead? Are there any alternatives that would sound more natural to a native ear?

Comment: Both when and where seem good to me

Comment: *Night* here is hardly "a point in time." 20:45:33 is a "point in time." A *night* is a prolonged period of time during which many things can happen. It's okay to use *where* because the writer is conceiving (consciously or not)  of this time period as a "(temporal)  place" where things happen. *When* can be used  but it changes the meaning to a *time period*.

Comment: @Clare Please post it as an answer.